# Fire jquery upon reaching bottom of page (only once)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below script, which is initialising a function upon reaching the bottom of the page (with a 1px threshold, as it doesn't seem to work without this). It is workming fine, but I'd like it to only work when reaching the bottom of the page the first time, if a user scrolls back up and down, nothing should happen.

Any suggestions?

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 1) ) {
        // Function goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: Set a flag and change it after the function is triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some flag for that:

```
var hasScrolled = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(!hasScrolled && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 1) ) {
        hasScrolled = true
        // Function goes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add another variable that would keep track if the user has scrolled already. 
`

```
scrolled = false;
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height() - 1) && !scrolled) {
        // Function goes here
    scrolled = true;
}
```